# Upload de Arquivo

Tags: php, html, post

Eu tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $nome_temporario = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $nome_real = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["name"];
    copy($nome_temporario, "/public_html/publico/$nome_real");
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="Arquivo" id="Arquivo"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Apagar"/>
</form>
```

Gostaria de saber o que há de errado, pois quando tento fazer o upload, ele aparece esta mensagem de erro:

> Warning: copy(/public_html/publico/teste.txt) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/opeao802/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mensagem de erro diz que a pasta `/public_html/publico` não existe. Verifique se ela existe e se você tem permissão para salvar arquivos dentro dela.

**Verifique a localização exata da pasta**

Coloque o nome relativo da pasta ou completo `../publico` ou `/home/opeao802/public_html/publico`

Ex:

```
<?php
    $nome_temporario = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $nome_real = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["name"];
    copy($nome_temporario, "../publico/$nome_real");
?>
```

Ou

```
<?php
    $nome_temporario = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $nome_real = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["name"];
    copy($nome_temporario, "/home/opeao802/public_html/publico/$nome_real");
?>
```

Comment: Estou com o acesso geral, e executando o código dentro do servidor, ta tudo liberado no cpanel. A pasta existe sim, mas não sei pq não consegue copiar pra dentro '-'

Comment: veja a resposta editada

Comment: Tentei, ele não apareceu mais a mensagem de erro, mas também não fez upload do arquivo T.T

Comment: qual das opções você usou? teste utilizar a `/home/opeao802/public_html/publico/` para garantir

Comment: esta opção mesmo eu utilizei.

Comment: não vejo mais nenhum erro, aparece alguma mensagem ou warning novo?

Comment: eu tinha colocado public ou invés de publico na resposta, por acaso você nao tem uma pasta public ai o arquivo pode estar dentro dela

Comment: não não, eu tinha percebido, mas não alterei nada. tudo certo quanto as pastas

Comment: Caso ainda não esteja ainda, testa colocar permissão`777` na pasta p ver

Comment: cara, agora que vi, ele copiou para a pasta anterior a pasta que informei. o que será que ocorreu?

Comment: tudo certo velho, eu errei o caminho mesmo.

Comment: Posta como está seu código agora

Comment: Blza q bom q deu certo